# Flexbox: выравнивание одного элемента на главной оси по краю контейнера

Tags: css, flexbox

Как во флексбоксах оторвать один крайний элемент от группы элементов, выровненных justify-content-ом по центру главной оси, и прилепить к правому или левому краю контейнера?

К примеру:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
 
}

.block1, .block2, .block3 {
  border: 5px solid red;
  margin: 0 3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block1">Блок1</div>
  <div class="block2">Блок2</div>
  <div class="block3">Блок3</div>
</div>
```

Как блок1 прижать к левой стороне, или блок3 к правой, но чтобы остальные два остались в центре? Margin не важен, я написал лишь чтобы впритык не были.

Comment: Можно увидеть ваш HTML и CSS? Пока что, лично я, не очень понимаю задачи

Comment: Ну вот к примеру 
https://codepen.io/Black_Fire/pen/VWEaRR
как блок1 прижать к левой стороне, или блок3 к правой, но чтобы остальные два остались в центре? margin не важен, я написал лишь чтобы впритык не были.

Comment: Босюь с помощью одного flex этого не сделать

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, так напишите это ответом к вопросу, а не как комментарий

Comment: Благодарю. Со стороны W3C консорциума является серьезным упущением не предусмотреть выравнивание по-горизонтали для отдельного элемента, в то время как почему-то для вертикального есть align-item/self.

Answer (score 3):

Получилось решить с блочной абсолютной вёрсткой

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.wrapper {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.block1,
.block2,
.block3 {
  border: 5px solid red;
  margin: 0 3%;
}

.block3 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block1">Блок1</div>
  <div class="block2">Блок2</div>
  <div class="block3">Блок3</div>
</div>
```